# php dynamic checkbox is checked

Tags: php

This is my all shipping method:

```
$Shipping = Shipping::find()->all();     

$allshp_mthd = [];
    foreach ($Shipping as $P_Shipping) {   
        $allshp_mthd[$P_Shipping->id_shipping]['id_shipping'] = $P_Shipping->id_shipping;
        $allshp_mthd[$P_Shipping->id_shipping]['shipping_method'] = $P_Shipping->shipping_method;
    }
```

output:

```
Array
(
 [1] => Array
    (
        [id_shipping] => 1
        [shipping_method] => free
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [id_shipping] => 2
        [shipping_method] => pickup
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [id_shipping] => 3
        [shipping_method] => country_wise
    )

 [4] => Array
    (
        [id_shipping] => 4
        [shipping_method] => api
    )

)
```

And this is my shipping method saved in database:

```
$ProductShipping = ProductShipping::find()->where(['id_product' => $id_product,'id_shop' => $current_shop])->all();

$shiping_name = [];
    foreach ($ProductShipping as $Product_Shipping) {   
        $Shpng = Shipping::find()->where(['id_shipping'=>$Product_Shipping->id_shipping])->one();        
        $shiping_name[$Product_Shipping->id_shipping]['id_shipping'] = $Product_Shipping->id_shipping;
        $shiping_name[$Product_Shipping->id_shipping]['shipping_method'] = $Shpng->shipping_method;
    }
```

output:

```
Array
(
[4] => Array
    (
        [id_shipping] => 4
        [shipping_method] => api
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_shipping] => 2
        [shipping_method] => pickup
    )

)
```

In php,I want all checkbox will be there with api,pickup checked in view.
How is it possible?
I am new in php so can't understand how to do this??

Comment: show your html what you have tried?

Comment: I have not create my html till now.

Comment: then use foreach and check condition then add checked in your checkbox if value found

Comment: Show me how ?please provide me code

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$output` contain your output of shipping detail as your question. I am assuming you have a checkbox for each category in your html.

```
//for picked check box
foreach($output as $ship)
{
     if($ship['id_shipping'] == 2 and $ship['shipping_method'] == 'pickup')
     {
          $checked = 'Checked="Checked"';
          break;
     }
}
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked;?> />
```

Do simmilar for other checkbox